# Can I add an image behind a single word in a paragraph

Tags: css, image, text, highlight

I want to add a brushstroke image behind certain words in a paragraph like this example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzjGn.png. I've tried adding a simple background to a span but the image extends past the padding and gets cut off. Eg:

```
.highlight1 {
  background: url(ImageUrl.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

Any help would be great!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2):

That code should not cause the background image to get cut off. It will, however distort the image which might not be desirable.

You may want to add some padding so that the text is inside the brush stroke.

```
padding: 5px 20px;
```

Or something like that.

I tested it as follows, and it seems to work:

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
}
span {
  background: url('https://www.onlygfx.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/grunge-brush-stroke-banner-2-17.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  padding: 5px 20px 10px 20px;
  margin: 0;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>
  
  This is a <span> Test </span>
 
</p>
```

Comment: I think this might be what I'm looking for! I also added a little negative margin so that the spacing between words stayed consistent. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use `background-size: cover;`

```css
p {
  font-size: 2em;
}
#abc {
  background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzjGn.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<p>aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa <span id="abc">aaaaa</span> aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, that still seemed to cut off part of the image for me though.